# Select numbers where not exist with a specific code

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select all numbers where COD = 'GV' but also select the numbers that do not exist with code 'GV'... number 4170 for example...

```
COD  NUM 
---- ----   
GV   4168    
SERV 4168    
GV   4169    
SERV 4169    
SERV 4170    
SERV 4171    
GV   4171
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally, *transcribed* what you asked for:

```
-- numbers for COD = GV
select num
from your_table
where cod = 'GV'
union
-- numbers for COD <> GV
select num
from your_table
where cod <> 'GV
```

Simplified:

```
select distinct num
from your_table;
```

as you, basically, want all numbers, regardless of the `COD` value.

Comment: I really want all the numbers with code 'GV' and those that do not exist with 'GV', partly it works, but as soon as I need more fields, they are duplicated

Comment: Could you provide desired output (based on "input" you provided so far)? It wouldn't hurt if you modified sample data and include "more fields" so that we'd see what you mean by them being "duplicated".

Comment: @AntonioDelicadoLópez . . . This answers the question that you have asked here -- and I think the answer should be accepted.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partitioned outer join:

```sql
WITH bounds ( min_num, max_num ) AS (
  SELECT MIN( num ),
         MAX( num )
  FROM   test_data
)
SELECT t.COD,
       n.NUM
FROM   (
         SELECT min_num + LEVEL - 1 AS num
         FROM   bounds
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= max_num - min_num + 1
       ) n
       LEFT OUTER JOIN test_data t
       PARTITION BY ( t.COD )
       ON ( n.NUM = t.NUM )
WHERE  t.NUM IS NULL
AND    t.COD = 'GV';
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( COD, NUM ) AS 
SELECT 'GV',   4168 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SERV', 4168 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GV',   4169 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SERV', 4169 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SERV', 4170 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SERV', 4171 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GV',   4171 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COD |  NUM
> :-- | ---:
> GV  | 4170
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c253a5810bf4919eb6476a21dae005ed)*